# Linking a select form with a switch case PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, select

I am trying to link a select form with a switch case statement.

booking.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['$usernamepassword'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
body {
    background-color: linen;
}
</style>
<h1 style='color:blue'>Book day!</h1>
<form method ="post" action='booking2.php'>
<select>    
  <option value="friday">Friday</option>
  <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
  <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
 </select>
    <input type="Submit" name="submit">
    <br>
    <br>
</form>
```

pbooking.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['$usernamepassword'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
    switch ($_POST["value"]) {
        case "friday":
            header('Location: friday.php');
            break;
        case "saturday":
            header('Location: saturday.php');
            break;
        case "sunday":
            header('Location: sunday.php');
            break;
    }
?>
```

I have created two documents.
The first document, booking.php contains the form.
In the form there is the dropdown.

On the second document, pbooking.php contains the switch case.
I am trying to link the switch off the value.
As the value changes the case changes, friday - saturday - sunday.
It doesn't work... returning undefined index line 7 ('value')
This would suggest to me that it needs to be linked off something else?
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give `name` attribute to your select type. Also change your action to `pbooking.php`

```
<form method ="post" action='pbooking.php'>
    <select name="value">    
      <option value="friday">Friday</option>
      <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
      <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
     </select>
 <input type="Submit" name="submit">
    <br>
    <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `name` attributes in `<select>` tag

like this:

```
<select name="value">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<form method ="post" action='booking2.php'>
<select name="value">    
  <option value="friday">Friday</option>
  <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
  <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
 </select>
```

Your `$_POST['value']` is not linked with any input

Answer (score 0):

Put `name="value"`

```
<select name="value">
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. I will not recommend deletion but I will request you to kindly explain why adding that code will solve OP's question. That should improve the quality of your answer.